# React-jest-enzyme: testing callback of child component that calls another function first before calling the callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-bootstrap

I am testing wether a callback that is passed to a child component is called after my button in the child component is clicked. I simulate the react-bootstrap button, `<Button></Button>`, by using the `.simulate('click')` function.

The problem is that the `onClick()` function of my button calls another function called `update()` and that function calls the `handleSave` callback passed to my child component. The `onKeyPress` function of the `<FormControl/>` element also calls the update function of my component. Here is how I have my child component setup:

```
    update(event) {              

       //Have to check to see if the key stroke is the enter key or if it comes from the button click.
       if(event.charCode === 13 || event.type === 'react-click'){

       // Have to use this get the ref value because this.refs.input.value doesn't work.
       var input = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.input);

       input.value = '';
       this.props.handleSave();
   }
}

render(){

    return( 
       <Form>
         <FormControl type="text" ref="input" onKeyPress={this.update.bind(this)} placeholder="Enter Note" />
         <Button onClick={this.update.bind(this)}>Submit </Button>
       </Form>
    )
}
```

That is why my `update()` function has a check to see if came from `charCode==13`, that is the charCode for the enter key, or the button click because both save the info that is in the `<FormControl />`

I have my test setup this way:

```
describe('Input', () => {

const mockHandleText = jest.fn();
const mockHandleSave = jest.fn();
const props          = {handleSave: mockHandleSave}
let input            = shallow(<Input {...props} />);

   describe('when entering a note', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
            input.find('Button').simulate('click', {
                charCode: 13
            });
    });


    it('adds the note to state', () => {
        expect(props.handleSave).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
 });
```

A weird thing is that I have to pass an object as a second parameter to the `.simulate()` function because if I don't it will give me an error saying cannot read charCode of undefined but when a pass an object, the object doesn't even have to have an event property, then it just says

`expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled() 
Expected mock function to have been called.`

Also If I don't pass in the object with some property then it also breaks my other test that I have for a callback on the `onChange` function of my  element. I left it out of the code sample for the sake of simplicity and just uploaded the code that is giving me problems. I am also using a bootstrap form with  and  . The full code is on my github at github.com/Alebron23.

Comment: And in my github it is in the Notetaker repo.

Answer (score 0):

Enzyme's shallow method doesn't render the whole DOM tree, just the  most shallow level. You'll not be able to find nested children using it. In the docs for shallow (https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/shallow.md), they discuss that if you need to assert any behavior on child components, you'll have to use something other than shallow().

Your other options are to either use render(), or more likely- since render() is static and you want to test side effects- to fully mount()
 the component (https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/mount.md) instead.

Comment: No that didn't work when I tried to use mount instead of shallow. I still got the same error. But the function that I am calling inside of my component from the onClick function is still apart of the component so it should still be available to call since shallow lets you test your component as a unit.